# Getting a TypeError: $ is not a function script error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I am trying to send a mail, using web services in asp.net in html and sending the info through a jquery ajax function.
the html form is as follows.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
<h2>DROP ME A LINE</h2>                          
<!-- contact from -->
<form class="form" id="form" >
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Name" required/>
<input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email" required/>
<textarea name="message" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="8" ></textarea>
<input type="button" class="mt-button medium outline" name="submit" id="submit" value="Send Message" onclick="javascript: SendMail();">
                            </form> 
                                        <span class="sending">
                                            sending...
                                        </span>
                                        <div class="mess center">
                                        </div>  
                            <!-- contact from end-->
                        </div>
```

and the javascript function as follows

```
<script type="text/javascript">


                function SendMail() {
                    var domain = location.host;
                    var serviceurl = location.protocol + "//" + domain + "/wp-content/themes/me_wp/mail/SendMail.asmx/SendUserMail";

                    var name = $("#name").val();
                    var fromMailId = $("#email").val();
                    var message = $("#message").val();


                    $.ajax({
                        url: serviceurl,
                        data: "{ 'name': '" + name + "','fromMailId': '" + fromMailId + "','message': '" + message + "' }",
                        dataType: "json",
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        success: AjaxSuccess,
                        error: function (xmlHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert(textStatus);
                            alert(errorThrown);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

```
function AjaxSuccess(response) {
    var result = response.d;
if(result ==true)
{
$('#sending').val("Thank you, message sent");
alert('mail sent');
}
}   
</div>
</div> 
</div>
```

when i try to run this i get a 
TypeError: $ is not a function
    var name = $("#txtName").val();
script error in firebug
can anyone please help me out with this.

Comment: Have you referenced jQuery prior to this code? Also, you don't assign values to setter methods, you pass them. I think you mean `$('#sending').val("Thank you, message sent")` in your callback function.

Comment: did you include the jQuery library in your page or whether `jQuery.noConflict()` was used?

Comment: @George yes i have used Jquery at other places in the code, the latter please ignore.

Comment: @ArunPJohny yes, the library was included.

Comment: @OsmanShareef I think the error is in your AjaxSuccess method. You used $(#sending.val()=......) I don't think this reference is correct. You should have used $('.sending').val('Thank you, message sent'); "sending" is a class so use (.) not #

Comment: @xK0nB1n i made those changes, now getting this as a script error which says ReferenceError: AjaxSuccess is not defined
success: AjaxSuccess,
function AjaxSuccess(response) { var result = response.d; if(result ==true) { $('#sending').val("Thank you, message sent"); alert('mail sent'); } }

Comment: @OsmanShareef Edit your question and put the entire code.. show us where have u included the jquery file.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have the jQuery library loaded before your $ or jQuery calls. What version of the library are you using and what browser and version are you using? Keep in mind there are two different versions (jQuery 1 and 2).

You question has "i get a TypeError: $ is not a function var name = $("#txtName").val(); script error", but within your code that you've posted, you don't have that shown. Can you post more or all of your code? Need to verify the placement of the jQuery library, but also see where the $("#txtName").val(); is coming from...

Comment: This is not the comment section.

Comment: Contradiction in itself.

Comment: if you want to comment. Answer few of the questions. Get ranked and then keep going commenting. :)